# First day of the year with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function to determine the first day of the year. All steps seem correct but the last one. What is wrong here?

```js
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

console.log('Current Year: '+currentYear) // -> correct

// Create a new Date object for January 1st of the current year
const januaryFirst = new Date(currentYear, 0, 1);

console.log('January First: '+januaryFirst) // -> correct

// Convert the Date object to an ISO string
const result = januaryFirst.toISOString().substring(0, 10);

console.log('Result: '+result) // -> 2022-12-31 , wrong , it shows the last day of previous year.
```

No idea what is wrong with it.

I am looking for a function to determine the first day and last day and of the actual year.

Thank you

Comment: `toISOString` will produce the date/time in UTC zone, where it can be a different day at the moment it is your midnight (local time).